# Adding external dependencies to ant project (IDEA Android project)

Tags: java, android, ant

In the documentation to [socket.io-java by nkzawa](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) is mentioned that to add ant dependency should be used [next snippet](http://nkzawa.github.io/socket.io-client.java/dependency-info.html):

`<dependency org="com.github.nkzawa" name="socket.io-client" rev="0.1.1-SNAPSHOT">
  <artifact name="socket.io-client" type="jar" />
</dependency>`

In which file and how I should include it? How I should compile my application after that?

Comment: I know, not an answer, but consider abandoning Ant and going with Maven or Gradle: so much more convenient in combination with Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [socket.io-client documentation](http://nkzawa.github.io/socket.io-client.java/dependency-info.html) is misleading. ANT has an extension called [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for performing dependency management, but it is not bundled by default.

Once setup you can list your project's dependencies in an ivy.xml file or within your build.xml using the [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path">
   <dependency org="com.github.nkzawa" name="socket.io-client" rev="0.1.1" />
</ivy:cachepath>
```

I have included a more complete example below. It details how to configure your ANT build to automatically setup ivy.

I am not an android programmer, so not able to recommend the best build tool. What I can say is that adding dependency management to your build process is a very good idea. ANT pre-dates more modern tools like Maven and Gradle that have this feature baked in.

## Example

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <!--
    ================
    Build properties
    ================
    -->
    <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

    <!--
    ===========
    Build setup
    ===========
    -->
    <target name="install-ivy" description="Install ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
        <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path">
           <dependency org="com.github.nkzawa" name="socket.io-client" rev="0.1.1" />
        </ivy:cachepath>
    </target>

    <!--
    ===============
    Compile targets
    ===============
    -->
    <target name="build" depends="resolve" description="Project build logic goes here">
       <javac .... classpathref="compile.path">
       </javac>

       ...
    </target>

    <!--
    ===============
    Clean-up targets
    ===============
    -->
    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to manage dependency with ant you'll need to use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)
But I agree with Bart Kiers - switch to [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), especially as you're already using IDEA.